# Canvas Node.js, не могу установить

Tags: node.js, canvas

При введении в консоль `npm install canvas`, выводит следующую ошибку:

```js
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\soft\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\soft\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\soft\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:282:31
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:148:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "D:\\soft\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\soft\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Fluiser\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release\\canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Fluiser\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\Release" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Fluiser\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'D:\soft\nodejs\node.exe D:\soft\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Fluiser\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=C:\Users\Fluiser\node_modules\canvas\build\Release --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Fluiser\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1011:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "D:\\soft\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Fluiser\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Fluiser\node_modules\canvas
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Не имею понятия, что делать.

Comment: Написано же - питон поставь.

Comment: Ставил, от версии 2.7.3 до 3.7.3

Comment: @Fls в PATH то его прописали?

Comment: И консоль перезапустил после этого?

Comment: Всё выше сказанное, я уже делал.

Answer (score 1):

Получил точно такую же ошибку. Решение оказалось простым - под 12й нодой не работает, а под 10й - всё собирается. Так что надо поставить node.js версии 10.

Я использую [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases), чтобы было проще переключаться между версиями.